# Qt: Is it possible to use QStandardItemModel.takeRow() to remove nested rows?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

My goal is to take a row out of a `QStandardItemModel` that I am displaying with `QTreeView`.

I was hoping to do this with `takeRow()`. [The documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html#takeRow) for this method says:

> ```
> list-of-QStandardItem QStandardItemModel.takeRow (self, int row)
>
> The list-of-QStandardItem result
> ```
>
> Removes the given row without deleting the row items, and returns a
>   list of pointers to the removed items. The model releases ownership of
>   the items. For items in the row that have not been set, the
>   corresponding pointers in the list will be 0.

It takes no parent parameter, which would be needed to specify a row location in a tree, and seems to only take away top-level rows. Is there a way to use `takeRow()` to take a child/grandchild of a top-level row? For instance, can it be used to take row 02 below?

```
|--row 0
|  |--row 00
|  |--row 01
|  |--row 02
|--row 1
|--row 2
```

Using something like `model.takeRow(2)` only removes row 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only apply `takeRow()` at the level of the entire model if you want to remove top-level rows. To remove a row that is a child of another item in the model, apply `QStandardItem.takeRow()` to the *parent item* (`QStandardItem`) of the row you wish to remove.

So to remove child row `r` from the parent `QStandardItem` called `item`:

```
item.takeRow(r)
```